# how to migrate an existing website hosted on wordpress to kubernetes on GKE?

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, migrate

I want to migrate an existing website hosted on wordpress to kubernetes using GKE or even gce but i do not know where to start. I haven't written any code yet. I tried to find solutions online but I didn't find anything on migrating a website HOSTED on wordpress to kubernetes.

1. How can i fetch the database
2. What should the dockerfile look like
3. How many yaml files should be included
4. How many pods do i create

Answer (score 2):

You can create and run with on one pod also but it's depends on your wensite traffic.

You can start with the two pod initially one for Mysql and another for wordpress application it self.

You can create two yaml for the same and one docker and apply it to kubernetes cluster.

Follow this simple guide and start your wordpress on kubernetes :

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/